# why setting bounds origin makes the subview move to another direction in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, bounds

I'm trying to figure out the difference between frame and bounds in iOS, basically the Bounds refers to the views own coordinate system while Frame refers to the views parent coordinate system. But,
I have a viewA and a viewB, ViewA is the parent of ViewB,
if I change the bounds of ViewA from (0,0,100,100) -> (50,0,100,100), viewB shold move to right because it's coordinate system move to right by 10 right?
but ViewB move to left!
See the code and behavior:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var viewA: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewB: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        viewA.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(50, 0, 240, 377)
    }
}
```

[image: before click]
[image: after click]

Shouldn't the center view move to right not left because we +30?

Comment: You are modifying the layer bounds, not the view bounds. Also, you will get inconsistent results if you mix constraints with modifying frames and bounds directly.

Comment: I think the view bounds and layer bounds are same thing, and I did try view bounds, same behavior

Comment: You have only modified one view and you haven't called `layoutIfNeeded`. If you have constraints then you will find that when you do this, the views will jump back to their original positions.

Comment: When updating a UIView, set the frame, not bounds and do it directly on the view, not on the layer. The bounds should always have an origin of 0,0 or things get weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `UIView frame vs bounds` you'll find lots and lots of discussion, along with plenty of articles/blogs that go into great detail on the differences.

But -- to give you a quick answer to why your view moves **left** instead of **right** (as you expected)...

Suppose I have a 200x200 `UIView`. I add a 400x200 `UIImageView` as a subview, with this image:

[image]

and I constrain the image view Top and Leading to the "container" view (make sure `.clipsToBounds = true` on the container view).

It will look like this (on a yellow background):

[image]

which should be no surprise.

Now, let's change the container view's bounds to:

```
containerView.bounds.origin.x = 50.0
```

we will see this:

[image]

The image view does not get "pushed" 50-points to the right... nor does it get "pulled" 50-points to the left.

What we've done is told the container view to: *"display the `bounds` rectangle from **your content** (your subview(s))"*:

[image]

That's how a `UIScrollView` works... if the scroll view's content is larger than the scroll view's frame, we can drag the content... which changes the scroll view's `.contentOffset` which, in turn, changes the scroll view's `bounds`.

Quick `UIScrollView` example showing that:

```
class ScrollBoundsVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let infoLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "img400x200") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!")
        }
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        infoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        view.addSubview(infoLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: img.size.width),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: img.size.height),
            
            scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

        ])
        
        imageView.image = img
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        infoLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        infoLabel.textAlignment = .center
        infoLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        infoLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
        
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        updateInfo()
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateInfo()
    }
    func updateInfo() {
        infoLabel.text = "\nscrollView bounds:\n\(scrollView.bounds)\n\nimageView frame:\n\(imageView.frame)\n"
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this as I scroll to the left:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Here is about the same thing, but instead of a `UIScrollView` we'll use a "container" `UIView` ... each tap anywhere will increment the container view's `.bounds.origin.x` by 20-points:

```
class ContainerBoundsVC: UIViewController {
    
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let containerView = UIView()
    let infoLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "img400x200") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!")
        }
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        infoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        containerView.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        view.addSubview(infoLabel)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: img.size.width),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: img.size.height),
            
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),

            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])

        imageView.image = img

        containerView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true

        infoLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        infoLabel.textAlignment = .center
        infoLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        infoLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        updateInfo()
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        containerView.bounds.origin.x += 10.0
        updateInfo()
    }
    func updateInfo() {
        infoLabel.text = "\ncontainerView bounds:\n\(containerView.bounds)\n\nimageView frame:\n\(imageView.frame)\n"
    }
}
```

Of course, this has only addressed your specific condition. If you spend some time reading up on `frame vs bounds` you'll see that it comes into play in a much more critical context when you start applying scaling and rotational transforms to your views.

Comment: That's really clear, I did read some article, but most of them are talking the difference between bounds and frames, like have a rotation or something like that...Anyway, your answer help me understand how scrollview works too, thank you!